# SQL join 2 tables to 1 table

Tags: mysql

I am at the task of joining 3 tables:
Task, Unit, and Building.

The task table has a column for a unit and a column for a building.
Any single task is assigned to only a building OR a unit, never both. 
Thus one column in every record is always null. There are 6100 records in the task table.

when I use this JOIN:

```
select * from task t
join building b on b.id = t.building_id;
```

I get 628 rows.  This is the correct total of building tasks.

When I use this JOIN

```
select * from active_task at
inner join unit_template ut on ut.id = at.unit_template_id
```

I get 5472 rows. This is the correct number of unit tasks.
If I add them up 5472+628 =6100 this is the correct # of rows in the task table.

When I run this Query:

```
select * from task t
inner join unit ut on ut.id = t.unit_id
inner join building bt on bt.id = t.building_id
```

I get zero rows.  I need my query to retrieve 6100 rows.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: basic ER]

Comment: What if you write query iteratively? Just add one `JOIN` at first and make sure you get the expected results. **ONLY** after that add another join

Comment: @denonth: for what reason? Optimizer rewrites `INNER JOIN + ON` to an implicit join with `WHERE` before execution

Comment: If this got him confused

Comment: thanks Zerkms, but what you described is actually what I have done to reach this point.

Comment: @denonth: the question about lack of results. Rewriting that query would change nothing

Comment: @GRY: so? Why don't you share your **intermediate** results then? We need to guess? PS: in the middle of the post you have a query with `unit_template`, not `unit` - this confuses us

Comment: "I need my query to retrieve 6100 rows." -- how so? After 2 inner joins you get an **intersection** of 628 and 5472 rows. Which, obviously, can be 0. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @zerkms: with all due respect to Jeff, this explanation is pretty confusing. It explains set addition and subtraction (`UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`), not set multiplication (`JOIN`).

Comment: @Quassnoi: the first example there is an intersection of two sets, `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @zerkms: which two sets?

Comment: @Quassnoi: uhm, whole tableA and whole tableB

Comment: @zerkms: you mean `units` and `buildings`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: `task & unit`, and `(task & unit) & building`

Comment: @zerkms: they are not union-compatible, intesection operation is not defined on them. As I told, Venn diagrams are the wrong tool for defining set multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a left join:

```
select * from task t
left join unit ut on ut.id = t.unit_id
left join building bt on bt.id = t.building_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    task t
LEFT JOIN
        unit ut
ON      ut.id = t.unit_id
LEFT JOIN
        building bt
ON      bt.id = t.building_id
        AND t.unit_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the matches given by both queries why not unifying:

```
SELECT * from task t JOIN building b ON b.id = t.building_id
UNION
SELECT * from active_task at JOIN unit_template ut ON ut.id = at.unit_template_id
```

As long as the two task tables have the same number of fields that should be enough (otherwise filter the desired columns in the select statements).