# how to join 2 tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to join my variants table to my products table so that I am able to get the product_id from both tables, how can I put this into my existing query..?

I've tried to add it not working.

```
 $query = query("
 SELECT * 
   FROM products 
 FULL OUTER 
 JOIN variants WHERE product_id=" . escape_string($_GET['add']). " ");
```

Comment: Cast that GET value as an integer to prevent SQL injection. IE: $add = (int)$_GET['add'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join 2 tables to 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746248/sql-join-2-tables-to-1-table)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are looking for an `inner join`, not a `full outer join`. You'll also want to specify the column you are joining both tables on:

```
$query = query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM products 
    JOIN variants ON variants.product_id = products.product_id 
    WHERE products.product_id =" . escape_string($_GET['add']). " ");
```

*Note: I'm assuming `product_id` is a column on both the `variants` and `products` table. If, for example, the `product_id` of `products` is just `id`, you'll want to change the join condition to:

```
ON variants.product_id = products.id
```