# SQL: How to select all records from 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying with SQL query to select all the projects from 1 table and from table 2 all the emails.
The final result should:

```
project_name student_email         
project 1    email 1
```

This for all the records I have.
The 2 tables look like:

Student table:

[image]

Projects table:

[image]

What I would like to know is the query to select all the project and specify also the emails associated from students table

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: This question seems to me as duplicate, try to search stack a little bit before asking - e.g. shows the way in principle how to accomplish what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746248/sql-join-2-tables-to-1-table .

Comment: `select p.*, s.email from projects p join students s on s.student_id=p.student_id` did the trick?

Comment: Yes did it the trick that nice thanks :)

Comment: Is it OK for you repeating e-mails along the rows ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: as an example 1st row `Test project lemis@gmx.com`, 2nd row `My SQL lemis@gmx.com` and 3rd row `my new project lemis@gmx.com`. E-mails are repeated for each row for an individual student.

Comment: So are the emails for the students and a student can have more projects so emails can repeat as associated with the project of the student :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be:

```
Select pro.project_name, st.student_mail from student st join projects pro on (st.student_id=pro.student_id)
```

You can add a where at the end.

pro. and st. -> These 2 are Aliases, just so i don´t have to type Table´s full name.

If you want to receive data from 2 or more tables, u should use Joins.

For more information about "joins":

-https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp